# allowing multiple users to connect to a server

Tags: java

Ok so what I am trying to make is a quiz program that will allow multiple users to connect and view other teams scores to be able to compare with them. However I am having issues in that I can't figure out how to get multiple users connected to the same server to be able to use it simultaniously. Currently a single user can connect at a time.

Any advice?

(thread, one is meant to be created for each user/team that connects)

```
package QuizProgram.ServerComponents;

import QuizProgram.Frames.Team;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 16/06/2015.
 */
public class PointsServer
{
   private static int lastArrayPosition=0;
   protected static ArrayList<TeamThread>threadsList;
   protected static ArrayList<Team>teamsList;
   protected static PrintWriter toClient;
   protected static Scanner fromClient;
   protected static ServerSocket serverSocket;
   protected static Socket socket;

   public static synchronized void setupList()
   {
      teamsList=new ArrayList<Team>();
      threadsList=new ArrayList<TeamThread>();
   }

   public static synchronized ArrayList<Team> getTeams()
   {
      return teamsList;
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeam(String teamName)
   {
      teamsList.add(new Team(teamName));
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeam(String teamName, int initialScore)
   {
      teamsList.add(new Team(teamName,initialScore));
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeamScore(String teamName, int addScore)
   {
      boolean found=false;
      int count=0;
      String currentTeamName="";
      Team currentTeam;

      while(!found && count<teamsList.size())
      {
        currentTeam=teamsList.get(count);
         currentTeamName=currentTeam.getTeamName();

         if(currentTeamName.equals(teamName))
         {
            currentTeam.setScore(currentTeam.getScore()+addScore);
            found=true;
         }
      }
   }

   public static void setupServer()
   {
      try
      {
         System.out.println("setting up server");
         serverSocket=new ServerSocket(2004);
         System.out.println("waiting for connection");
         socket=serverSocket.accept();
         System.out.println("connection established");
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public static void setupThreads()
   {
      threadsList.add(new TeamThread(socket));
      //TeamThread thread=new TeamThread(teamName,toClient,fromClient,socket);
      //thread.start();
      threadsList.get(lastArrayPosition).start();
      lastArrayPosition++;

      try
      {
         socket.close();
      }
      catch(Exception ex){}
   }  
}//class
```

(how the server calls are made when starting server)

```
package QuizProgram;

import QuizProgram.ServerComponents.PointsServer;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 17/06/2015.
 */
public class ServerTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      PointsServer.setupList();

      while(true)
      {
         PointsServer.setupServer();
         PointsServer.setupThreads();
      }

   //   PointsServer.setupServer();
   //   PointsServer.setupThreads();
   }//main
}//class
```

(Points server which houses msot of the methods for the server to use and store info)

```
package QuizProgram.ServerComponents;

import QuizProgram.Frames.Team;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 16/06/2015.
 */
public class PointsServer
{
   private static int lastArrayPosition=0;
   protected static ArrayList<TeamThread>threadsList;
   protected static ArrayList<Team>teamsList;
   protected static PrintWriter toClient;
   protected static Scanner fromClient;
   protected static ServerSocket serverSocket;
   protected static Socket socket;

   public static synchronized void setupList()
   {
      teamsList=new ArrayList<Team>();
      threadsList=new ArrayList<TeamThread>();
   }

   public static synchronized ArrayList<Team> getTeams()
   {
      return teamsList;
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeam(String teamName)
   {
      teamsList.add(new Team(teamName));
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeam(String teamName, int initialScore)
   {
      teamsList.add(new Team(teamName,initialScore));
   }

   public static synchronized void addTeamScore(String teamName, int addScore)
   {
      boolean found=false;
      int count=0;
      String currentTeamName="";
      Team currentTeam;

      while(!found && count<teamsList.size())
      {
        currentTeam=teamsList.get(count);
         currentTeamName=currentTeam.getTeamName();

         if(currentTeamName.equals(teamName))
         {
            currentTeam.setScore(currentTeam.getScore()+addScore);
            found=true;
         }
      }
   }

   public static void setupServer()
   {
      try
      {
         System.out.println("setting up server");
         serverSocket=new ServerSocket(2004);
         System.out.println("waiting for connection");
         socket=serverSocket.accept();
         System.out.println("connection established");
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
         System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
   }

   public static void setupThreads()
   {
      threadsList.add(new TeamThread(socket));
      //TeamThread thread=new TeamThread(teamName,toClient,fromClient,socket);
      //thread.start();
      threadsList.get(lastArrayPosition).start();
      lastArrayPosition++;

      try
      {
         socket.close();
      }
      catch(Exception ex){}
   }
}//class
```

I can show the client code as well if needed though I'm pretty sure it's something on the server side i'm doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: You need to call `accept` more than once. Basically you call `accept` in a loop, get a socket and create a thread to handle it. That's your session with one client, and then in your main thread you loop back to your `accept`. That's the basic structure of multi-client server handling.

Comment: is that not being done in here

 while(true)
      {
         PointsServer.setupServer();
         PointsServer.setupThreads();
      }

since the accept is in setupServer and is being looped infinintely?

Comment: No. You repeatedly create a server socket (you shouldn't, and there's a good chance you'll be getting exceptions there). You only have one normal socket and you close it immediately after creating a thread. Neither the server socket nor the socket should be in static variables at all.